# Android Search Widget - Back Arrow Button Functionality

Tags: android, search, back-button, back, searchbar

I'm trying to add functionality to the Search Widget Back Button. Right now, it only closes the search bar. I also want it to close the search list and return the original list before the search.

[Search Widget Back Button Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3Jt7.png)

Attached is my search code.

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));


    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    handleIntent(intent);
}

private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        winelist = dbHelper.searchWineList(query);
        adapter.clear();
        adapter.addAll(winelist);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your `menu` xml codes so I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

there's a listener for SearchView which listens to the closing of search, have you tried having a callback there to reset the whole list?